# I want `Fast Rollup algorithm` search keywords

Tags: c++, algorithm, rollup

I currently working on data handling module,
and i need to roll up multiple identical records with aggregate function.

For example,

If we have below table,

```
---------------------------------
| Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Sum |
---------------------------------
|      A     |      B     |  12 |
|      A     |      B     |  23 | 
|      B     |      C     |  42 |
|      C     |      B     |  33 |
|      C     |      B     |  22 |
---------------------------------
```

After rollup we got

```
---------------------------------
| Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Sum |
---------------------------------
|      A     |      B     |  35 |
|      B     |      C     |  42 |
|      C     |      B     |  55 |
---------------------------------
```

I gathered all identical rows using hash id into a dictionary data structure. (like Hash Map, Tree etc)

Following is my c++ code

```
unsigned int Record::GetHashCode()
{
    unsigned int hash = 1;
    for(const auto dim : *this)
    {
        hash = 31*hash + dim.HashCode();        
    }

    return hash;
}

unsigned int Dimension::HashCode()
{
    // Just burrowed java's hash function
    // Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()
}

void Gatherer::Gather(const vector<Record>& records)
{
    for(const auto& record : records)
    {
        if(table.find(record.GetHashCode()) == table.end())
        {
            // No this record in table
            table[record.GetHashCode()] = record;
        }
        else
        {
            table[record.GetHashCode()]["metric"] += record["metric"];
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah, it's quite strightforward, and it's performance is not bad and not super good.

Problem is that in near future probably more dimensions to be added.
The number of dimensions will be 80 or more.
I afraid current hash based gathering is not fit for large dimension record.

So i'm searching for roll-up algorithm better than mine.

Is there paper or something for fast rollup algorithm? 
Any ideas are welcome!
Or if you are busy, just toss me search keywords is also welcome!

Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: Please go and have a simple google for that, I'm sure you can find something. If you have problems with that, we can help you out

Comment: Map-reduce does this, but is probably overkill. Have you considered a simple `std::map<Dimensions, int> m;` and then `m[element] += element_sum;`?

Comment: Are identical rows always stuck together like in your example or could there be e.g. another "A B" row at the end of the table?

Comment: Just curious - does this all get put into a database at some point?

Comment: You should search the internet for "Relational database Convert normal forms".  Some of the sites explain a process for removing duplicates from a relational table.

Comment: As long as you are rolling up by ALL dimensions, a hash approach is good.  If you are rolling up by SOME of the dimensions, that's a big topic.  Google for "star schema rollups" to get started.

Comment: Thank you every body!
It seems stack overflow inform me through email only answer not comments

I'm working sort - merge based group by.

Thanks again!